# В чем проблема? vk api php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть код для вывода комментариев из обсуждения. Все выводится, кроме фото. Не понимаю как быть. пишется в src "unknow"
Вот кусок кода

```
<?php
            // проверяем, есть ли прикрепленые файлы в записи, далее берем только изображения, можно вывести видео, опрос и т.д.
            if (!empty($attachments)) {
                foreach ($attachments as $attach) {
                    if($attach['type'] == 'photo') {
                   //  закомент.чтобы не оборачивало фото в ссылку   echo '<a href="'.$attach['photo']['photo_604'].'">';
                        echo '<img class="imgvk" src="'. $attach['photo']['photo_604'].'" >';
                 //       echo '</a>';
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: вывод всех ошибок включи

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: правил описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, неправильная вложенность и ключи. В объекте фото нет ключа photo_604, зато есть ключ sizes в котором лежит массив с размерами и ссылками на фото.

```
if (!empty($attachments)) {
 foreach ($attachments as $attach) {

  if ($attach['type'] == 'photo') {
   foreach ($attach['photo']['sizes'] as $size) {

    if ($size['type'] === 'm') {
     echo '<img class="imgvk" src="' . $size['url'] . '" >';
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Описание объекта фото - https://vk.com/dev/objects/photo.
Описание размеров фото - https://vk.com/dev/photo_sizes (отсюда можешь выбрать нужные тебе размеры для условия).

И не забывай проверять на существование ключей.

Comment: ооо! спасибо вам за помощь, действительно, не все посмотрел до конца.